# Como colocar diferentes textos para "sim" e "não" no Visualg?

Tags: visualg, portugol

Comecei recentemente com programação, e estou fazendo um algoritmo que adivinha a idade do usuário, e estou usando o Visualg para praticar a lógica de programação.

Como colocar comandos de `sim` ou `não` no Visualg, e caso a pessoa escolha `sim`, apresente o texto `A`, caso ela escolhe `não`, apresente o texto `B` e continue realizando as próximas perguntas.

Até agora cheguei nessa parte:

```
algoritmo "valores"
    var
        N1,S,S2,S3: inteiro
inicio
    Escreva ("Ola,vou adivinhar a sua idade.Pense em um numero de 1 a 10: ")
    Leia (N1)
    S <- N1 * 2
    Escreval ("Ok,multipliquei esse numero por 2 e a soma é ",S,".Agora agora vou adicionar 5")
    S2 <- S + 5
    Escreval ("A soma entre ",S," e 5 é ",S2,".Sabendo disso, vou multiplicar por 50")
    S3 <- S2 * 50
    Escreval ("A multiplicação de ",S2, " e 50 é ",S3,".")
    Esreval ("Você ja fez aniversario esse ano?")
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Se não me engano é o `se`, `entao` , `fim se` dá uma olhada no manual...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma variável `X` do tipo literal (texto)

```
var
    N1,S,S2,S3: inteiro
    X: literal
```

Fazer a leitura de `X`, atribuindo um valor:

```
Escreval ("Você ja fez aniversario esse ano?")
Leia(X)
```

Verificar se `X`, é igual a `sim`:

```
se X = "sim" entao
    Escreval (A)
senao
    Escreval (B)
fimse
```

Espero ter ajudado, caso não esteja claro, ou esteja com dificuldade, basta comentar.

Comment: Só não entendi esse tipo "literal" que você falou.
Para que ele serve?
Você sabe de algum lugar aonde eu posso pegar mais informações desses "tipo"?
De qq forma,obgd!

Comment: Esse tipo literal, seria tipo (texto), também conhecido como String em outras linguagens de programação. Aqui você pode achar algumas informações sobre a Linguagem, porém não está 100% completo: http://www.eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem.htm

Comment: Obrigado!
Ajudou muito.

Comment: Aonde eu encaixo o texto que eu quero colocar? e como eu encaixo?

Comment: aonde está Escreval(A), coloque assim Escreval("Aqui está o texto que você deseja apresentar para o usuário"), esse texto só será apresentado, se o usuário preencher "sim", sendo todos em minusculo

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo os comandos que o membro Vitor me forneceu ficou assim e funcionou.`algoritmo "valores"
var
   N1,S,S2,S3,Idade : inteiro
   Soma_tudo,Data_nascimento : inteiro
   Soma_tudo2,Idade2 : inteiro
   X: literal
inicio
      Escreva ("Ola,vou adivinhar a sua idade.Em que ano você nasceu?  ")
      Leia (Data_nascimento)
      Escreva ("Pense em um numero de 1 a 10: ")
      Leia (N1)
      S <- N1 * 2
      Escreval ("Ok,multipliquei o ",N1," por 2 e o resultado é ",S,".Agora agora vou adicionar 5")
      S2 <- S + 5
      Escreval ("A soma entre ",S," e 5 é ",S2,".Sabendo disso, vou multiplicar por 50")
      S3 <- S2 * 50
      Escreval ("A multiplicação de ",S2, " e 50 é ",S3,".")
      Escreval ("Você ja fez aniversario esse ano?  ")
      Leia (x)
      se X = "sim" entao
      Escreval ("Ok.Vou somar 1766 no resultado final.")
      Soma_tudo <- S3 + 1766
      Escreval ("Somando ",S3," com 1766,obterei o resultado de ",Soma_tudo)
      Escreval ("Agora vou subtrair o resultado de ",Soma_tudo," com o valor do seu ano de nascimento,que no caso é",Data_nascimento)
      Idade <- Soma_tudo - Data_nascimento
      Escreva ("Deu ",Idade,".O primeiro digito é o numero que você pensou.Os outros 2 é a sua idade.")
      senao
      Escreval ("Ok.Vou somar 1765 no resultado final")
      Soma_tudo2 <- S3 + 1765
      Escreval ("Somando ",S3," com 1765,obterei o resultado de ",Soma_tudo2)
      Escreval ("agora vou subtrair o resultado de ",soma_tudo2," com o valor do seu ano de nascimento, que é ",data_nascimento)
      Idade2 <- Soma_tudo2 - Data_nascimento
      Escreva ("Deu ",Idade2,".O primeiro digito é o numero que você pensou.Os outros 2 é a sua idade")
      fimse
fimalgoritmo`